# preserving a folder from being removed at build by github-action

Tags: github-actions, adonis.js

adonis js cleans build folder every time you trigger a new build as a result public upload folder will be removed this created a lot of issue for me and Im trying diffrent methods to solve this.
Im not currently using github actions to build my project and I was wondering if it can help me on this matter by this order or somthing like this on every commit:

1. copy build/tmp folder
2. build project by running yarn build command
3. past the copied folder from step 1 back to build/tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who came here like me, I found the configuration. You can change local disk configuration.

/config/drive.ts

```
{ local: { root: Env.get('STORAGE_ROOT'), } }
```

In this case I created a variable in the .env with the absolute path

Comment: is it going to be an issue developing on windows but production host use linux?

Comment: No, if you do it the same way, you can configure the .env differently in production and local. Or if you look at this configuration, you'll see that it points to the local /tmp/uploads directory. "Application.tmpPath('uploads')" , so just change that location when publishing to a different directory